# How do we find the signs of trigonometric ratios

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

[image]

This is the image my textbook uses for finding whether the ratios are +ve or -ve.

Here , i feel they mean to  say that tan (+x) = tan x since b and a are +ve . We can tell it by looking at the x and y axis But I want to know if they talk about sin(+x) , how do we know if OP is +ve or not.

Can we also say that x = 1 since it is a radian measure of 1 unit.

Comment: An easier method is that the coordinates of a point on the unit circle (the circle of radius $1$ centered at the origin) are $(\cos \theta, \sin\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle measured counterclockwise from the positive $x$-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How do we know if OP is +ve or not?**
In the unit circle, OP is always defined as positive.

**Can we also say that x = 1 since it is a radian measure of 1 unit?**

Remember the definition of $s = r \times \theta$ . When
$ s =x, r = 1,\theta = x, x=1 \times x$, can we draw conclusion x=1?

**How do we find the signs of trig ratios?**

The following [trig plots](https://www.geogebra.org/m/Cb2jWUPS) are very helpful to understand the signs of trig ratios. Just play through the link. Once you understand it, you do not need to remember it.

$\color{blue}{Blue}: \sin \theta:  >0 (Q1,2), <0 (Q3,4)$

$\color{red}{Red}: \cos \theta:  >0 (Q1,4), <0 (Q2,3)$

$\color {pink}{Pink}:  \tan \theta:  >0 (Q1,3), <0 (Q2,4)$

[image]

Comment: Amazing it is. Thanks a lot. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4100701/883022 Pls do take a look.