# Finding proof for trigonometric ratio of 90+theta

Tags: trigonometry

When finding trigonometric ratios for 90+theta. Why don’t we make the diagram like this ? I see we are not getting an angle of 90 degree. So , can’t we say there is no values of trigonometric ratio possible for 90+theta.[image]

https://www.math-only-math.com/trigonometrical-ratios-of-90-degree-plus-theta.html. So , on this site I checked the proof for this. Below is the passage needed to understand this proof. What I didn’t get is how is sin theta = FE/OE

Take a point C on OA and draw CD perpendicular to OX or OX’.

Again, take a point E on OB such that OE = OC and draw EF perpendicular to OX or OX’.

From the right-angled ∆ OCD and ∆ OEF we get,

∠COD = ∠OEF [since OB ⊥ OA]

and OC = OE.

Therefore, ∆ OCD ≅ ∆ OEF (congruent).

Therefore according to the definition of trigonometric sign, OF = - DC, FE = OD and OE = OC

We observe that in diagram 1 and 4 OF and DC are opposite signs and FE, OD are either both positive.

Again we observe that in diagram 2 and 3 OF and DC are opposite signs and FE, OD are both negative.

According to the definition of trigonometric ratio we get,
sin (90° + θ) =
FE/
OE

Comment: Doesn't the reference also say sin (90° + θ) =FE/OE?

Comment: *"Why don’t we make the diagram like this?"* Um ... You got the image from a site that *does* make the diagram like that, so what's your point? :) ... Instructors are allowed to use different approaches to trig (or *any* topic). I choose to start w/right-triangle trig for acute angles, deriving as much lore (relations and identities) as possible. I then let the lore drive exploration beyond the bounds of the First Quadrant (see, eg, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/145828/409)) before ever introducing the Unit Circle. This serves a narrative of math as a journey of discovery.

Comment: @Blue I drew a blue colour trifle using edit I,e triangle EOD

Comment: @BrightStar The perpendicular for triangle EOD is ED. But yes , there is no 90 degree angle. FE /OE means of triangle EFO. That is not where the 90 is theta angle is present

Comment: @Blue The link and your thinking is great.

Comment: @Blue Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Rider Sorry that I do not understand your comment "The perpendicular for triangle EOD is ED".  In $\triangle EFO, \sin \angle EOF=\sin (90^\circ +\theta)$.  All you said in your question is correct, except that "What I didn’t get is how is sin theta = FE/OE"  - where does this "sin theta = FE/OE" come from?  If you can clarify this, that would be helpful.

Comment: @BrightStar It was in the online site. I also didn’t get how it is FE/OE

Comment: The online site said this:  sin (90° + θ) = FE/OE.

Comment: @BrightStar oh yes. How is sin (90+theta) = FE/OE. . Very sorry for such a typo. Must have disturbed you for no reason. I extremely apologise

Comment: OK, I understand now:-).  Let me write up an answer.

Comment: Please read page 9 of the linked document for general definition of  sine function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

We need to extend the [definitions of trig function](https://online.math.uh.edu/MiddleSchool/Modules/Module_4_Geometry_Spatial/Content/UnitCircleTrigonometry-TEXT.pdf) from special case in a  right triangle to general case in a  circle.

In the above graph,  \begin{align}\angle COD=\theta, \angle EOC=90^\circ,\angle EOD=90^\circ+\theta \end{align}

By definition,  \begin{align} \sin \angle EOD=\sin (90^\circ +\theta)=\frac{FE}{OE}  \end{align}